# Load view on button click with Angularjs in single page application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am very new to AngularJS. This is my first project so please forgive me if my question is very basic.

I am created a page using simple HTML and put three button on it.
On these button click I want to load views in the lowel part of screen.

Index.html

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="tab" ng-controller="TabControlController">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Environments')" ng-click="Views/EnvironmentsView.html">Environments</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'SIT_Downloader')" ng-click="Views/SITDownloaderView.html">Download PCP Client</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Users')">PCP Users</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Environments" class="tabcontent" ng-controller="environmentController">
        <div>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="SIT_Downloader" class="tabcontent" ng-controller="SITDownloaderController">
        <div>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Users" class="tabcontent">
        <div>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Bootstrap.js

```
var MyApp= angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
            {
                templateUrl: 'Views/EnvironmentsView.html',
                controller: window.environmentController
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
```

views are very simple as of now...

```
<h3>PCP Users</h3>
<p>This screen will be used to add/remove users</p>
```

Can anyone help me to understand what I am missing here or redirect me to some page with full example of this.

This is single page application.

Comment: can you create fiddle? in controller it should be environmentController instead of window.controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problem in your sample.

**1-** change  `<button ng-click=".." ></button>` to `<a href="/YORE ROUTE"></a>`

> you can use button also but you should crate a function that changes the current route to new route.

```
 <button ng-click="changeRoute('/home')" >Home</button>
  $scope.changeRoute = function(newRoute){
     $location.path(newRoute);
  }
```

**2-** wrong syntax for define `controller` in route.(put controller in each route)

**3-** Don't need to multiple `ng-view`

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0VMnFiRIfkPcJ25FrpkX?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Hadi for your help... Just one more point... This code is working with inline HTML. but when I create separate file it doesn't work...

routerApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/Environment', {
        template: 'Views/EnvironmentsView.html',
        controller: 'environmentController'
    })
    .when('/PcPDownload', {
        template: '<div><h2>{{title}}</h2><h3>{{shortTitle}}</h3><p>{{text}}</p></div>',
        controller: 'SITDownloaderController'
    })
         .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

Comment: For separate file you should use `templateUrl` and put the path of file.

Answer (score 3):

You can try instead of calling a function onclick of a button ,just link the route with anchor tag

```
 <a href="#/your route"></a>
```

Maintain the routes in separate js file
like:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app.home').config(appRoutes);
  appRoutes.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

  function appRoutes($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../yourhtmlfile.html',
        controller: 'controllerName',
        resolve: {}
      })


  }
})();
```

Also you dont need to have multiple ng-view for each view
have a single ng-view

```
    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

this helps in loading the html page when you click on the  tag and loads the corresponding html file.

Comment: I tried above code but it don't work for me.and for every loaded Html I need different controller...

Comment: for every route you can have the controller